# QuickText is not a "valid Tab" error when deploying Profiles

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, tab, quick-text

I'm deploying a `Profile Foo` from VCS to an org. SFDC reports a deployment error

```
You can't edit tab settings for QuickText, as it's not a valid tab
```

Yet if I look in the target org under Tab Settings, I can see an entry for `Quick Text`

How do I deploy this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two `QuickText` tab entries because Classic and Lightning have separate `QuickText tabs` when enabled in either UI.

I didn't see this within official docs, but Gearset has [How to resolve the "QuickText is not a valid Tab" error when deploying Profiles](https://docs.gearset.com/en/articles/2912616-how-to-resolve-the-quicktext-is-not-a-valid-tab-error-when-deploying-profiles) which hints at it. Both can be separately enabled in their respective UIs under

`Setup --> Quick Text Settings --> Enable Quick Text`.

*Classic*

[image]

*Lightning*

[image]

---

However, saying all that - your particular issue is through the Metadata API (MDAPI). It doesn't retrieve multiple entries in the metadata when you retrieve `profile + QuickText` - **it only retrieves the tab settings for the Classic tab**. **The Lightning QuickText tab settings don't appear to be retrievable/deployable in the MDAPI.**

So, this issue will typically need to solved by matching your target org to your source by either

- enabling quick text in classic UI
- Enable chat (`Setup --> Chat Settings`) in Lightning if you don't use Classic. This will automatically enable quick text in Classic as mentioned in [Enable Quick Text](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.quick_text_enable.htm&type=5)

> Quick text is automatically enabled in Salesforce Classic orgs where
> Chat is enabled

And then match the `QuickText` *classic* tab settings to be equal to your source (tab hidden, default off, default on) so it doesn't show as a diff or attempt to deploy.

In terms of the UI, through testing I've found the following to be true:

- Top `Quick Text` tab setting is for *Lightning*
- Bottom `Quick Text` tab setting is for *Classic*

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the target org does not have `Quick Text` enabled

```
Setup | Quick Text Settings | Enable
```

The more curious bit is that when you enable `Quick Text`, you will see two (2) entries in Tab Settings for the Profile as shown here:

[image]

So, QuickText not enabled - one entry; enabled - two entries. I have no idea why but sure is confusing.